Modal logic with an omniscient actual world
(This post is similar to but different to another post I have since deleted because it actually digressed on a topic tangential to what I originally wanted to ask and which is what this post is about.)
In the book In Contradiction (2 ed., 2006), chapters 5 and 6, logician and analytic philosopher Graham Priest defines the semantics of a certain formal logic, with extensional negation, conjunction and disjunction, and an intensional implication, which he calls $\Delta$, and mentions that Richard Routley's relevant logic $\mathbf{DK}$ is "essentially, $\Delta$ minus the irrelevancies". My question is whether a certain "quirk" of the semantics can be associated to an axiom schema valid in the class of Kripke frames with this "quirk," like how the schema $\Box \alpha \supset \alpha$ is valid in exactly the frames where the accessibility relation is reflexive. However, this "quirk" is not a simple condition on the accessibility relation, but also depends on ditinguishing an actual world among the worlds of the frame, and a property Priest calls the "omniscience" of the actual world.
Focusing on just the propositional fragment of $\Delta$, a Kripke frame is a triple $\mathcal F = \langle \mathcal W, w_0, \mathcal R \rangle$, where $\mathcal W$ is the set of worlds of $\mathcal F$, and $\mathcal R$ an accessibility relation on $\mathcal W$, as usual, but $w_0 \in \mathcal W$ is the actual world of $\mathcal F$. Moreover, if $\Omega$ is the set of atomic propositions, and if $\mathcal V = \{ 0, 1 \}$ is the set of truth-values, then a valuation over $\mathcal F$ is a function $\nu : \mathcal W \times \Omega \to \mathcal P(\mathcal V)$ such that, for every $p \in \Omega$ and $w \in \mathcal W$, $\nu_w(p)$ is a set (!!!) of truth-values, excluding the empty set, so $\nu_w(p) \in \{ \{ 1, 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0 \} \}$, where $p$ is said to be true (resp. false) at $w$ under $\nu$ just in case $1 \in \nu_w(p)$ (resp. $0 \in \nu_w(p)$). Hence, the logic is paraconsistent, since propositions can be both true and false (and indeed the semantics entail that the rule of explosion fails). Valuations are extended to the extensional connectives in the usual way, but for implication, the truth-conditions are:

$1 \in \nu_w(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ iff, for every $w' \in \mathcal R$ such that $w \mathcal R w'$, if $1 \in \nu_{w'}(\alpha)$, then $1 \in \nu_{w'}(\beta)$.
$0 \in \nu_w(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ iff, for some $w' \in \mathcal R$ such that $w \mathcal R w'$, both $1 \in \nu_{w'}(\alpha)$ and $0 \in \nu_{w'}(\beta)$.

(Priest actually defines $\rightarrow$ to be contraposible, i.e. such that for every $w' \in \mathcal R$ such that $w \mathcal R w'$, if $0 \in \nu_{w'}(\beta)$, then $0 \in \nu_{w'}(\alpha)$, but regardless, we can define a contraposible implication in terms of $\rightarrow$ by $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta := (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \land (\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha)$, so this is not an important difference. At this point, it may be worth pointing out that $\Box$ and $\Diamond$ can be defined in terms of $\rightarrow$ as well, by $\Box \alpha := \neg \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ and $\Diamond \alpha$ $:=$ $\neg \Box \neg \alpha$, satisfying the obvious truth-conditions.)
Validity in a frame $\mathcal F$ means truth at the actual world of $\mathcal F$ under every valuation over $\mathcal F$. $\vDash \alpha$ iff $\alpha$ is valid in every frame, and $\Gamma \vDash \alpha$ iff, for every frame where all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ are valid, so is $\alpha$. The author notes that, in the above semantics, modus ponens fails: $\{ \alpha \rightarrow \beta, \alpha \} \nvDash \beta$. This is similar to modal logics where, unless $\vDash$ is restricted to reflexive frames, modus ponens fails for strict implication. However, he says that a stronger (and possibly better) condition is that the actual world be omniscient, where $w \in \mathcal W$ is omniscient just in case $w \mathcal R w'$ for every $w' \in \mathcal W$. This implies reflexivity, and then some more. Thus, Priest restricts $\vDash$ to frames where the actual world is omniscient, so modus ponens holds, as well as other useful inferences, like $\{ \alpha, \neg \beta \} \vDash \neg (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ and $\{ \alpha \rightarrow \neg \alpha \} \vDash \neg \alpha$.
My question, in more detail, is this: does there exist a schema corresponding to the omniscience of the actual world? (Over normal modal logics, I suppose.) In the sense that the frames where this schema is valid are exactly the frames where the actual world is omniscient. I have never heard of this property of "omniscience" before reading In Contradiction, so I would also welcome references to the relevant literature (pun not intended) where I could read on the proof theory of Kripke frames with an omnisicent actual world (or other omniscient worlds).
